# Lerna specify run order

Tags: lerna

In my monorepo, I have 3 packages `package1`, `package2`, `package3`, each package contains a npm script named `build`.

However, these packages are not linked together. I.e. there are no `require()` in any of those packages linking to a sibling package.

From the root folder, I run `lerna run build`. It seems to run `build` of the packages in the alphabetically order.

Is there a way to specify the order to run the `build` commands of these packages?

`--sort` won't work because they are not linked.

Comment: Any luck on finding a way to specify build order?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't specify the order, you specify the topology by including a package as a dependency of another.

If `package1` needs to be built before `package2` you add `package1` to the dependencies of `package2` in the latter's `package.json` file. If you do not want `package2` to directly depend on `package1` (e.g. on production) you can still add it into `devDependencies` and Lerna will understand the dependency.

From `lerna -h`:

> --sort           Sort packages topologically (dependencies before dependents).
>                      Pass --no-sort to disable.                       [boolean] [default: true]

**Note** Some commands can be ran ignoring this topology, for example from [lerna exec's --parallel option documentation](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/exec#--parallel):

> completely disregards concurrency and topological sorting

Comment: You saved my life.

Comment: This way really messes when you try to remove or update other dependencies in a project that contains the Lerna package.

Answer (score 4):

`lerna run build --include-dependencies --stream`

[--include-dependencies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lerna/filter-options#--include-dependencies) this flag can help

Answer (score 1):

You can first build your shared package and after that trigger another build.

Ex :

`yarn workspace @shared run build && yarn lerna run build`